# Stripping end part of URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Having a small issue and hoped to get a few suggestions on how to proceed.

I have a site that goes through a payment form using post and sends back a long url with a query I just want to get rid off. The form uses hidden fields and I am not sure why it sends back a query string... but trying to work with it.

This is a typical url that gets sent back is:

> http://www.example.com/testsite/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=200&lang=en&layout=details&order_number=VVF1019218&view=orders&charset=utf-8&clientAccnum=333333&clientSubacc=1111&initialPrice=30.00&initialPeriod=2&Code=840&customer_fname=Ky&customer_lname=Williams&email=kywilliams@gmail.com&zipcode=&country=US&order_pass=p_ro4VmHBS&state=IN&city=&address1=&context=65748571b98f45543245d0d7a9b&pmid=20&flexId=5647365-1fe6-43a0-9936-e9b0fc80c2aa&formDigest=83746543829384756

I would like the url to be turned into the following, with the rest of the url cut off. The order_number is dynamic so that changes at times.

> http://www.example.com/testsite/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=200&lang=en&layout=details&order_number=VVF1019218&view=orders

So when the url is sent to our server I would like .htaccess to cut off everything after `view=orders`. Is this possible? I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "view=orders" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

No luck so far. Hope to get pointed in the right direction. Thanks so much!

Comment: as you can't control what url-params they send you'll need a redirect instead of a rewrite.

Comment: Thank you. I will research redirect instead of trying rewrite, and see if I can work with that. Maybe I can redirect to the same url with some of the url stripped out. All the other info is account info we are trying to make sure site users do not see that. Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at what you've tried, that doesn't work because of the `""` around `view=orders`. They shouldn't be there. But that would still only give you `http://www.example.com/testsite/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*view=orders) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1?%1 [R=301,L]
```